# Speeding up the insertion of null rows into a large Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a Pandas data frame with hundreds of millions of rows that looks like this:

```
Date      Attribute A    Attribute B    Value
01/01/16  A              1              50
01/05/16  A              1              60
01/02/16  B              1              59
01/04/16  B              1              90
01/10/16  B              1              84
```

For each unique combination (call it `b`) of `Attribute A` x `Attribute B`, I need to fill in empty dates starting from the oldest date for that unique group `b` to the maximum date in the entire dataframe `df`. That is, so it looks like this:

```
Date      Attribute A    Attribute B    Value
01/01/16  A              1              50
01/02/16  A              1              0
01/03/16  A              1              0
01/04/16  A              1              0
01/05/16  A              1              60
01/02/16  B              1              59
01/03/16  B              1              0
01/04/16  B              1              90
01/05/16  B              1              0
01/06/16  B              1              0
01/07/16  B              1              0
01/08/16  B              1              84
```

and then calculate the coefficient of variation (standard deviation/mean) for each unique combination's values (after inserting 0s). My code is this:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()
max_date = df['Date'].max()
for name, group in df.groupby(['Attribute_A','Attribute_B']):
    idx = pd.date_range(group['Date'].min(),
                        max_date)

    temp = group.set_index('Date').reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    coeff_var = temp['Value'].std()/temp['Value'].mean()
    final = pd.concat([final, pd.DataFrame({'Attribute_A':[name[0]], 'Attribute_B':[name[1]],'Coeff_Var':[coeff_var]})])
```

This runs insanely slow, and I'm looking for a way to speed it up.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> This runs insanely slow, and I'm looking for a way to speed it up.
>   Suggestions?

I don't have a ready solution, however this is how I suggest you approach the problem:

1. Understand what makes this slow
2. Find ways to make the critical parts faster
3. Or, alternatively, find a new approach

Here's the analysis of your code using [line profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler):

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.028074 s
File: <ipython-input-54-ad49822d490b>
Function: foo at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def foo():
     2         1          875    875.0      3.1      final = pd.DataFrame()
     3         1          302    302.0      1.1      max_date = df['Date'].max()
     4         3         3343   1114.3     11.9      for name, group in df.groupby(['Attribute_A','Attribute_B']):
     5         2          836    418.0      3.0          idx = pd.date_range(group['Date'].min(),
     6         2         3601   1800.5     12.8                              max_date)
     7                                           
     8         2         6713   3356.5     23.9          temp = group.set_index('Date').reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
     9         2         1961    980.5      7.0          coeff_var = temp['Value'].std()/temp['Value'].mean()
    10         2        10443   5221.5     37.2          final = pd.concat([final, pd.DataFrame({'Attribute_A':[name[0]], 'Attribute_B':[name[1]],'Coeff_Var':[coeff_var]})])
```

In conclusion, the `.reindex` and `concat` statements take 60% of the time.

A first approach that saves 42% of time in my measurement is to collect the data for the `final` data frame as a list of rows, and create the dataframe as the very last step. Like so:

```
newdata = []
max_date = df['Date'].max()
for name, group in df.groupby(['Attribute_A','Attribute_B']):
    idx = pd.date_range(group['Date'].min(),
                        max_date)
    temp = group.set_index('Date').reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    coeff_var = temp['Value'].std()/temp['Value'].mean()
    newdata.append({'Attribute_A': name[0], 'Attribute_B': name[1],'Coeff_Var':coeff_var})
final = pd.DataFrame.from_records(newdata)
```

Using timeit to measure best execution times I get

- your solution: `100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop`
- improved concat: `100 loops, best of 3: 6.67 ms per loop`

Details see this [ipython notebook](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/61dcd3678beb3e814613c4ddc0ac2036)

Note: Your mileage may vary - I used the sample data provided in the original post. You should run the line profiler on a subset of your real data - the dominating factor in regards to time use may well be something else then.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my way is faster than the way that you set up, but here goes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2016', '1/5/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/4/2016', '1/10/2016'],
                   'Attribute A': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Attribute B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'Value': [50, 60, 59, 90, 84]})

unique_attributes = df['Attribute A'].unique()

groups = []
for i in unique_attributes:
    subset = df[df['Attribute A'] ==i]
    dates = subset['Date'].tolist()
    Dates = pd.date_range(dates[0], dates[-1])
    subset.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    subset.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(subset.index)
    subset = subset.reindex(Dates)
    subset['Attribute A'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    subset['Attribute B'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    subset['Value'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    groups.append(subset)

result = pd.concat(groups)
```